# Can I declare <%@page~ contentType~ pageEncoding~%> or taglib like JSTL only once by using <jsp:include/>?

Tags: spring, jsp, include

I had to declare

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="true" %>
```

these three lines for each page of jsp file in my Spring MVC project.
I made header.jsp with the three lines and, and used 

into other jsp pages.

but it won't work.
All my other jsp pages still needed to declare the three lines.

Any way not to declare the three lines for every page, and only declared by once?

Comment: An Interceptor can set the contentType and encoding

Comment: I found out that It is possible to declare JSTL and Session in jspf file and use the jspf file for entier pages by adding jsp-config in web.xml.

Comment: I wil think about interceptor for Encoding! Thanks.